# How to aggregate an AtomicReferenceArray?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, concurrency

I've an application that keeps a `AtomicReferenceArray<Bucket>`, where a `Bucket` is an immutable container of statistics (sum, avg, max, min, count). More details here: https://github.com/asarkar/txn-stats/blob/master/README.md

At some point, I want to aggregate the buckets into a larger bucket. I'm wondering what memory order mode should be used. Currently, plain is used, which is the weakest, and has the semantics of reading as if the variable was declared non-volatile.

I've read Doug Lea's famous paper [Using JDK 9 Memory Order Modes](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/j9mm.html), although I admit to skipping over some stuff. The only other relevant question I found regarding "draining" an `AtomicReferenceArray` is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9138723/839733), and it's not much.

Suggestions?

Comment: Does your reference to the JDK 9 Memory Order Modes imply that you are talking about the API of Java 9 or newer?

Comment: @Holger yes, `VarHandle` was introduced in JDK 9.